# Twilio usage records for a twilio number

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I would like to know it is possible to get usage records for a twilio number.

It seems the api returns usage for a twilio account only.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/usage-records#usage-categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Data from the [Usage Records API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/usage-records) are aggregates for an entire account, not at the phone number level.

You could use the [Messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message) and [Calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call) resources to calculate your own usage though. You'd need to collect [all the messages sent to the number and from the number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list) and similarly collect [all the calls made to the number and placed from the number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list-get-filters).

If you are trying to collect this data in order to charge a customer, then can I recommend using [subaccounts](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/subaccounts) instead. Then you can use the usage records on the subaccount and just get the details you need.

Comment: The purpose is to get analytics for a twilio number used for a campaign. Yes, we can use the Messages and Calls resources. I assume it may be time consuming since we need to iterate through list to get the count. Am I correct.

Comment: It might be time consuming. You can increase the page size for API requests to 1000 if that helps. Alternatively, you might try running that campaign under a subaccount, that might still work for you.